# Compile vtk and ves libraries for Android on Linux unbuntu64

Tags: android, c++, build, android-ndk, vtk

I have followed the instructions in this link: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VES/Developers_Guide

I have downloaded VES, Andoid ndk-r8b, Android Studio (which has Android sdk), adb, ant.

And following the instructions:

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/home/ahrgm/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b
cmake -P configure.cmake
cd build 
make -j4
```

the following error appears:

> loading initial cache file
>   /home/ahrgm/VES/CMake/toolchains/TryRunResults.cmake CMake Error at
>   /home/ahrgm/VES/CMake/toolchains/android.toolchain.cmake:745
>   (message):   Could not find any working toolchain in the NDK. 
>   Probably your Android NDK   is broken. Call Stack (most recent call
>   first):   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:93
>   (include)   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
>
> CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may
>   be not be built correctly. Missing variable is:
>   CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR CMake Error: Error required internal CMake
>   variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly. Missing
>   variable is: CMAKE_C_COMPILER CMake Error: Could not find cmake module
>   file:
>   /home/ahrgm/VES/Apps/Android/CMakeBuild/build/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
>   CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may
>   be not be built correctly. Missing variable is:
>   CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR CMake Error: Error required internal CMake
>   variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly. Missing
>   variable is: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER CMake Error: Could not find cmake
>   module file:
>   /home/ahrgm/VES/Apps/Android/CMakeBuild/build/CMakeExternals/Build/vtk-android/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
>   CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage CMake
>   Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make[2]: *** [CMakeExternals/Stamp/vtk-android/vtk-android-configure] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vtk-android.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all]
>   Error 2

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Dunno if you have solved your problem. Are you aware that you can now build vtk for android and iOS directly and that you should not expect support for VES anymore? Have you tried it?